# Mysql out of space in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, I need something like this:

```
1) if('out of space' == mysql_error($link))
2) if(10 == mysql_error($link))
3) if(true == mysql_error('out of space'))
4) if(... whatever ....)
5) if(1024 == mysql_errno($link))
{
   echo 'DB is out of space';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for errno code 1021 (ER_DISK_FULL) and/or 1041 (ER_OUT_OF_RESOURCES)

```
switch( mysql_errno($link) ) {
case 1021:
  // handle ER_DISK_FULL
  break;
case 1041:
  // handle ER_OUT_OF_RESOURCES
  break
...
```

see also
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_disk_full
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_out_of_resources
(and maybe 1037, 1038)

Comment: My site is running on SHARED HOSTING environment and I have 1024MB for MySQL database. Which one would be most appropriate?

Comment: I'd handle both, 1021 and 1041, in that case. If your provider implemented that "feature" via linux' disc quota the underlying system code should be `122` (if I'm not mistaken). And this system error code should be within the error message you can retrieve via mysql_error(). I would just ask the provider if and when I could do a little stresstest on the database, fill it up to the limit and make a protocol of the errno/error messages.

Comment: Does it give me information about the who mysql space itself of server or just my part which is 1024MB?

Comment: Depends in part on how the provider has set it up. When an error code indicates that mysql couldn't write the data your script could a) test the mysql_error message for the system code "122" and/or "disc quota exceeded" and/or b) check how much space your database uses e.g. with data from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html

Comment: Thanks. I think it is better for me to stick to manual checks because it looks more complicated since I have no control over my web space or DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysql_errno($link) == 10) {

}
```

or...

```
if (strpos(mysql_error($link), 'out of space') !== false) {

}
```